# How hide "timeline" from Facebook page plugin on responsive desing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, responsive-design

I'm using "@media only" on my css file to get two diferent styles.

In my desktop vercion I have the Fecebook page plugin showing the "timeline" of the page, but I want to hide the "timeline" when "@media only" condition load the style of mobile vercion.

There is a way to manipulate the "timeline" atribute with jquery?

[Timeline atribute in html...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpq8W.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook terms, you are not allowed to hide elements of a Social Plugin. But you can do the following:

- Listen to the resize event with JavaScript
- If the window size changes, change the attribute of the Page Plugin with JavaScript
- Use `FB.XFBML.parse('page-plugin-id')` to parse the Plugin again, with the new attributes